# How to find out if CocoaPods was installed in my Mac?

Tags: ios, cocoa, podfile

I want to know if CocoaPods was installed on my Mac. What should I type in terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute a sudo command in Terminal on your Mac, you must be logged with an administrator account that has a password. You can use the sudo command in the Terminal app to execute commands as a different user, such as the root user. After you enter the command, Terminal asks you to enter your password.

To check and know more about sudo , open terminal and type **man sudo**

Cocopods : CocoaPods is a library dependency management tool for OS X and iOS applications. we need Gems to install cocopods .

RubyGems is a package manager for the Ruby programming language that provides a standard format for distributing Ruby programs and libraries (in a self-contained format called a "gem"), a tool designed to easily manage the installation of gems, and a server for distributing them.

To install cocopods :
Open terminal and type **sudo gem install cocopods** , no need to use any Ruby manager (rvn).

If it needed to update gems then use
**$ gem update --system.**

Comment: Is cocoapods installed using sudo in my case ? I typed  - gem install cocoapods it showed the above mentioned error. I now tried the same command with sudo. And it is asking password now

Comment: I think yes, try to update the cocopods with below command
sudo gem install cocopods

Comment: If I update it will it have effects on other pod executions in my Mac?

Comment: Don't worry, it will not affect to the pods install in your current project unless you update the pod. To update the pod go to project directory and type 
pod update.

Comment: @AbdulAzizRustamOgli if it works mark it as an answer.

Comment: @AbdulAzizRustamOgli glad it works .. Happy Programming